# Creating a simple script to import user's first name , create local account and and password

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to create a simple powershell script that will import the user's first name from file, prompt to create a new password and loop on error when the password doesn't meet the password requirement based on the "ErrorVariable" if possible. If not, please advise.

```
# import user firstname from file
$firstname = $(Get-Content "C:\tmp\local\firstname.txt")

# prompt user for new password
$password = Read-Host "Hello, $firstname!! Please change your local admin account password. (Requirements: At least 8-characters, 1-Cap Letter, 1-Number) " -AsSecureString -Erroraction silentlycontinue  -ErrorVariable PasswordError 


# create new password
$password = $password
Get-LocalUser -Name "$firstname" | Set-LocalUser -Password $password -Erroraction silentlycontinue -ErrorVariable PasswordError

If ($PasswordError)
{
    "Unable to update the password. The new password does not meet the length or complexity."
}


If (-Not $PasswordError)
{
    "Password updated successfully!!"
```

See script above.........

Comment: What is the problem? If it is "*and loop on error*", you will at least *create a loop* somewhere...

Comment: You are piping all the values. But the error actions only occurs once the pipe has finished. So, the Errorvariable will only contain the LAST error that occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Think you could simply use try/catch - e.g.:

```
try {
    Set-LocalUser -Name $firstname -Password $password -Erroraction:stop
    write-host "Password updated successfully!!" 
}
Catch {
    write-error $_
}
```

If the operation succeeded you will get "Password updated successfully!!", otherwise it returns the error.